# RegEx matches perfectly but skips matches when replacing

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a text containing placeholders like `%%%NAME.suffix|DefaultValue%%%`.

The following RegEx is matching it perfectly (see [link](https://regex101.com/r/qR8uN5/71)): `%{3}((\w+)(?:\.(\w+))?)(?:\|([\s\S]*?))?%{3}`

But it skips matches when I replace them one by one in JavaScript (ES5, same in ES6 or later) using a while loop.

I'm ***not*** using a RexEx pattern in `String.replace(/a/gm, "b")` but a simple string `String.replace("%%%NAME.suffix|DefaultValue%%%", "DefaultValue")`.

```js
var soup = "%%%X.x|a%%% %%%Y.y|b%%% %%%Z.z|c%%%";

var m;
while ((m = regex.exec(soup)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    console.log(m[2] + " found: " + JSON.stringify(m, null, 2));
    soup = soup.replace(m[0], m[4]);
}
```

Result: the `Y` placeholder is skipped. **Why is that?**

Output:

```
X found: [ "%%%X.x|a%%%", "X.x", "X", "x", "a" ]
Z found: [ "%%%Z.z|c%%%", "Z.z", "Z", "z", "c" ]
```

Also see full code here: https://runjs.co/s/IcNbKwSCu

Comment: The actual regular expression as it appears in your code should be posted in the question. Links to external sites can break over time.

Comment: Because you are not replacing in-line, you are replacing the actual text that you search for matches, and when you change it, its length changes and the regex index starts pointing to the wrong location. You just need to use  `.replace` directly.

Comment: Also your regular expression cannot possibly have a zero-character match.

Comment: So, it seems to me all you need is `soup = soup.replace(regex, '$4')` if `const regex = /%{3}((\w+)(?:\.(\w+))?)(?:\|([\s\S]*?))?%{3}/g`

Comment: @pointy it is included in my question

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use `soup.replace(regex, $4)` directly because I first need to analyze the match and depending on the existence of `m[0]` to `m[4]` I need to make decisions about the value that is used for replacing. I also need to load values from other sources (e.g. database) before I can replace.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I had the same idea... but thought that this is not the case because the regex is executed against `soup` with every loop (a new search) and indices are re-created. **Am I wrong?**

Comment: It is not an issue. Pass a function to replace: `soup = soup.replace(regex, (x,$1,$2,$3,$4) => do_something_with(x,$1,$2,$3,$4))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you modify the string while regexing you start regexing a new string each loop. That seems rather chaotic.

Use a `.matchAll()`'s iterator:

**UPDATE**

Since the OP stated that only es5 is supported, just exec on the string's copy:

```js
var regex = /%{3}((\w+)(?:\.(\w+))?)(?:\|([\s\S]*?))?%{3}/g;

var soup = "%%%X.x|a%%% %%%Y.y|b%%% %%%Z.z|c%%%";
var soupCopy = soup;
var m;
while(m = regex.exec(soupCopy)){
    console.log(m[2] + " found: " + JSON.stringify(m));
    soup = soup.replace(m[0], m[4]);
}

console.log(soup);
```

The same with a capture group reference:

```js
const regex = /%{3}((\w+)(?:\.(\w+))?)(?:\|([\s\S]*?))?%{3}/g;

var soup = "%%%X.x|a%%% %%%Y.y|b%%% %%%Z.z|c%%%";

console.log(soup.replace(regex, '$4'));
```

Comment: Nice! Seems to work but unfortunately only in ES6+. My application is running with the Rhino JS engine based on ES5 so `String.matchAll` is not available :-(

Comment: Respect! So simple and working: Many thanks! Updated code example: https://runjs.co/s/YEcX7341v